# Am I using script inlining and thymeleaf action wrong? Want to switch thymeleaf action path

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

[A visual explanation of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuwvI.png)

I built a Spring Boot Application and from the search bar, I'm trying to search based on SKU and Make separately by choosing the dropdown button as shown in the picture. By default the code is searching for SKUs with no issues but I would love to switch back and forth from SKU and Make and change my thymeleaf action path from my form.

**Repository Class** (It consists two queries to search based on SKU and Make):

```
@Repository
public interface ExcelFileRepository extends JpaRepository<ExcelFile, Integer> {
@Query(value = "select * from excel_file e where e.sku like %:sku%", nativeQuery=true)
List<ExcelFile> findBySKU(@Param("sku") String keyword);

@Query(value = "select * from excel_file e where e.make like %:make%", nativeQuery=true)
List<ExcelFile> findByMake(@Param("make") String keyword);
```

}

**Service class:**

```
public List<ExcelFile> findBySKU(String keyword)
{
    return efRepository.findBySKU(keyword);
}

public List<ExcelFile> findByMake(String keyword)
{
    return efRepository.findByMake(keyword);
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@Controller
public class DBController 
{
@Autowired
private ExcelFileService efService;

@GetMapping(path={"/dbs","/searchSKU"})
public String findAll(ExcelFile e,Model model, String keyword) {
    List<ExcelFile> dbList;
    if(keyword == null)
    {
        dbList = efService.getAllData();
    }else {
        dbList = efService.findBySKU(keyword);
    }
    
    model.addAttribute("dbs", dbList);

    return "Db";
}

@GetMapping(path="/searchMake")
public String searchMake(ExcelFile e,Model model, String keyword) {
    List<ExcelFile> dbList;
    if(keyword == null)
    {
        dbList = efService.getAllData();
    }else {
        dbList = efService.findByMake(keyword);
    }
    
    model.addAttribute("dbs", dbList);

    return "Db";

    ... more code...
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" th:action="@{/searchSKU}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
            <label>Search by </label>
            <select name="searchTypes">
                <option>-SELECT-</option>
                <option th:value="searchSKU" id="searchSKU">SKU</option>
                <option th:value="searchMake" id="searchMake">MAKE</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="keyword"
                                            th:value="${keyword}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-success">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script th:inline="javascript">
    var makeAction = /*[[@{/searchMake}]]*/ '/searchMake';
    var skuAction = /*[[@{/searchSKU}]]*/ '/searchSKU';
    $("#searchTypes").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "searchMake") {
            $("#searchForm").attr("action", makeAction);
        }else if ($(this).val() == "searchSKU") {
            $("#searchForm").attr("action", skuAction);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Anyone who has experience with script inlining know how to deal with thymeleaf and changing th:action path?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

The way this worked is by creating two different search methods:

1. with path = searchSKU (disconnected from /dbs)
2. with path = searchMake

HTML: (Default search is by SKU. Added a reset button to go to main inventory page)

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" th:action="@{/searchSKU}">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
            <label>Search by </label>
            <select name="searchTypes" id="searchTypes">
                <option disabled>-SELECT-</option>
                <option value="searchSKU" id="searchSKU">SKU</option>
                <option value="searchMake" id="searchMake">MAKE</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="keyword" th:value="${keyword}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-success">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-1">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="resetButton" th:href="@{/dbs}">Reset</a>
</div>
```

Script Inlining on same HTML:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var skuAction = /*[[@{/searchSKU}]]*/ '/searchSKU';
    var makeAction = /*[[@{/searchMake}]]*/ '/searchMake';
    $("#searchTypes").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "searchMake") {
            $("#searchForm").attr("action", makeAction);
        } else if ($(this).val() == "searchSKU") {
            $("#searchForm").attr("action", skuAction);
        }
    });


    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Now the issue is that from main inventory page, changing from 'SKU' dropbox option to 'Make' dropbox option at first try works perfectly fine. After first try, when you search for make again, it redirects to searchSKU method again. Following images are example:

First try:
[FIRST TRY IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NDne.png)

As you can see in the image, the circled 'searchMake' will change back to 'searchSKU' and when I reclick on the Make dropdown option it won't work anymore.

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an answer?  It looks like you meant to add it to the question, instead.